# css media print check legal paper

Tags: css, printing

How to check in if the height age is equal heigth paper Legal ?

My code didn't work

```
@media and (min-height: 13in)  {
        @media print{
            #divbr{
                display: block;
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution :

```
 #divbr{
        display: none;
   }

   @media (min-height: 13in){
       @media print{
           #divbr{
                display: block;
           }
       }
    }
```